# How to create Resource with custom fields

Tags: csom, custom-field-types, project-server, resources

I need to create resources which might have custom fields. I've encountered the issue that, if the custom field is mandatory, then I get an exception after running `context.ExecuteQuery();`. This is my code:

```
resource.uid = Guid.NewGuid();
context.EnterpriseResources.Add(createNewEntityInformation(resource));
context.EnterpriseResources.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

And the method `createNewEntityInformation` is as follows:

```
EnterpriseResourceCreationInformation resourceInfo = new EnterpriseResourceCreationInformation();
resourceInfo.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
resourceInfo.Name = entity.name;
return resourceInfo;
```

I don't see any property in `EnterpriseResourceCreationInformation`, so how can I add the custom field values to the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by disabling the mandatory requirement in all ECF prior to creating the resources, then after the creation I just re-enable them.